# UNKNOWN_CHARACTER mark insterted after less than signs, null bytes after every char

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2

I'd like to ask if you met this before: unknown character marks right after tag openings. The view files are clean (UTF8), no sign of corruption, so is the application.

This is what shows on the frontend instead of the rendered navbar:

```
�� <�div class="navigation-container" style=" width:100%;"> <�nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="topmenu">
```

I really can't add any more to this question, hope you recognise it!

head of the hexdump for this partial:

```
0000000 3c0a 6964 2076 6c63 7361 3d73 6e22 7661
0000010 6769 7461 6f69 2d6e 6f63 746e 6961 656e
0000020 2272 7320 7974 656c 223d 7720 6469 6874
0000030 313a 3030 3b25 3e22 0a0a 2020 2020 6e3c
0000040 7661 6320 616c 7373 223d 616e 6276 7261
0000050 6e20 7661 6162 2d72 6e69 6576 7372 2265
0000060 6920 3d64 7422 706f 656d 756e 3e22 200a
```

[image]

Comment: What encoding do your http headers declare for the document? Looks like a classical miss match leading to miss interpretation by the browser.

Comment: If it means anything, the hex of that symbol is: efbfbd

Comment: headers specity utf8. a little progress: dev console shows, that after every character a null byte is inserted to the navigation partial.

Comment: Are you using any plug-ins or have you changed any configuration settings?

Comment: in the browser? no. I test it in incognito mode.

Comment: It looks like you are saving the file with an editor with the wrong encoding it could be like unicode since all characters in that section have a bad character before